# Django--django-admin.py on windows does not work

Tags: python, django

I am just starting Django these days but I cannot run this command

```
    django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

Well, CMD does not prompt to say that this command is not recognized. Instead, it just open up my Sublime with the file django-admin.py open. and of course no folder named myproject is created inside the current folder.

I managed to start a Django project by typing commands like

```
    python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

But when I omit the part about the absolute path information of django-admin.py, then the command does not work, saying python cannot find such a file inside the current directory.

is there any way I should try to use shorter commands? (PS: I do have C:\Python27\ and C:\Python27\Scripts\ in the PATH)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way ([recommended by the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/)) is to just copy django-admin.py to your project's directory.

Technical details: There are workaround in `setuptools` to make entry points work correctly on Windows, by installing a .exe file that will run correctly even if Python is not set as the default handler for .py files, but Django is not using `setuptools` but `distutils` directly. I am not aware of any discussion about moving to setuptools.

Alternatively you can set python.exe as the default program to open .py files, instead of your text editor.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! just that open .py using text editor is so much easier for editing

Comment: I just sent out a [pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/1812) about this just in case. We'll see what they think of it. In the meantime, if you use my patch to setup.py, you'll have django-admin.py in your PATH.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I solved it by not adding `.py` at the end of `django-admin`.  For example:  `django-admin startproject myproject`.  And I can still have Sublime Text open python files by default.

Comment: My answer dates back to 2013. The Django project, though it initially rejected my patch, ended up [switching to setuptools](https://github.com/django/django/pull/2116) with 1.7 (released Sep 2014).

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have had a similar issue on windows. I found that using django-admin as listed below worked.

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

Comment: this does not work since python complains that it cannot find this django-admin.py in the current folder

Comment: seems they say i should actually copy django-admin.py when i try to start my project. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was easy to copy the file django-admin.py into the folder that I wanted the stuff in. Navigate to the file in the command line and then run.

```
'python django-admin.py startproject myProject'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just started using python3.4 and I found everything (packages like pip and django) in c:\pythonpath\scirpts dir. Added that into system path and everything works good. e.g. django-admin startproject mysite